# Is the history of companies/people related to computing on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Do we also want to support questions that are not about hardware or software, but about a company or person that was important in the history of computing?

For example one could ask stuff about the history of Microsoft, IBM, Apple, Linus Torvalds, Konrad Zuse, etc.

Of course we don't really want questions about people's personal life, but questions about their actions and impact on the history of computing should be on-topic.

We must make sure that this kind of questions does not get too opinion-based, as history can often be interpreted multiple ways.

What do you think? On or off topic?

Related question: [Is computing history inherently on-topic?](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16/128)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shouldn't be on-topic.

People and companies make the devices and are not necessarily devices... Our little summary states this:

> Beta Q&A site for vintage-computer hobbyists interested in restoring, preserving, and using the **classic computer and gaming systems** of yesteryear.

Emphasis is mine. People and companies are clearly not classic computer or gaming systems from times like the 1900's thus are off-topic. Anyways, questions about their impacts would be kind of like this:

> What impact did {company/person} have during the {years like 1950}'s